# How can I control a .gtlf2 mesh animation in aframe with onmouseover event?

Tags: animation, aframe, gltf

I'm trying to control (start/stop) gtlf animations onmouseover. I found a good example but it relies on the model being in .json format:

Example: https://rexraptor08.github.io/animation-controls/

Source: https://github.com/rexraptor08/animation-controls

Problem is I'm not longer able export .json format from blender as the addon has been removed: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Per Piotr's answer below, the example above should also work with `.gltf` and `.glb` models, using the A-Frame `gltf-model` component and `aframe-extras`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use glTF animations using the [animation-mixer](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf) component.

First of all, you need to export your model with [Kupoman's exporter](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf). I've used the Khronos group one, but it has trouble with exporting models with multiple animations.

Once you have the model exported, just include [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders), so you can use the animation loader.

Then you can use it like this:

```
<a-entity gltf-model="url(model.gltf)"
   animation-mixer="clip: DoStuff;"></a-entity>
```

---

If you want to start an animation with any event, just create a [component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/component.html#register-a-component), which will set up the `animation-mixer`:

```
this.el.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
  this.el.setAttribute("animation-mixer", "clip", "DoStuff") 
})
```

Also be sure to check out Don McCurdys [guide](https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/11/06/creating-animated-gltf-characters-with-mixamo-and-blender/).

Comment: @peterwaldock no problem, glad i could help :)